# Length of initial_probs is not equal to the number of states

Tags: r, hmmlearn, seqhmm

I am new to R. While making a Hidden markov model we have to give the following parameters; initial prob, emission prob, transition prob, observations.
But I am getting the following error

> Length of initial_probs is not equal to the number of states

Can someone help me how to resolve this error?
Thanks in advance

Edit: Here is an example data which I uploaded on google drive

[Sample data on google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BuZMlxSg-F6KPN5xrQEA30_hEzGWNzJi/view?usp=sharing)

Here is the code

```
    library(HMM)
    library(seqHMM)
    library(TraMineR)
    library(markovchain)

    let_alphabet <- c("1", "0", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "S", "D", "UK")
    let_labels <- c("i","O","ii","iii","iv","v","vi","vii","viii","ix","x","Son","Daughter","Unknown")
    let_scodes <- c("1","0","P2","P3","P4","P5","P6","P7","P8","P9","P10","Sn","Daugt","NA")
    let_seq <- seqdef(letsdo, 1:3, alphabet = let_alphabet, states = let_scodes,labels = let_labels, xtstep = 14)

    init_hmm_let <- build_hmm(observations = let_seq, n_states = 2)
   #Transition prob
  trp <- seqtrate(let_seq)
#Initial prob
    inist <- c(0.53, 0.47)
#Emission Prob
    emisp <- matrix(NA, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
    emisp[1,]<- c(0.51,0.48)
    emisp[2,]<- c(0.58,0.41)
#Building the model
    init_hmm_let <- build_hmm( observations = let_seq, transition_probs = trp,
                                 emission_probs = emisp, initial_probs = inist)
```

Comment: Well, the error message seems pretty clear. Why not provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with some sample input data and the code you are actually running. Perhaps you are calling the function incorrectly?

Comment: This is the example data
EduM1 Preg# Gender
1 1 S
1 2 UK
1 3 D
1 4 D
1 5 D
0 1 S
0 2 D
0 3 S
0 4 D
0 1 D
0 2 S
0 3 D
0 4 D
0 5 D
0 6 S
0 7 D
0 8 S
0 9 S
0 10 S
@MrFlick

Comment: Edit your question to include this code so it can be properly formatted. Do not put this info in comments.

Comment: @MrFlick Kindly check, I edited my post.

Comment: I tried to run the code but `letsdo` was undefined.

Comment: I uploaded the dataset "letsdo" on google drive, and shared the link in my post. Kindly check @MrFlick

Comment: @MrFlick did you check the code.?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not going to download data files from remote sites. Questions should be self-contained for me to be interested in working on them, otherwise I just move on to the next one.